# Verify the exist of a var and update it

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a coffee dispenser, I would like if capsules have already been added to the "totcaps" variable then add more.

In a nutshell I wish that if never before the capsules had not been added, then add them, otherwise add them to the existing ones.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <script>
    /* Mess info/err */
    function writeMess(node, mess) {

      newmess = document.createTextNode(mess);
      node.replaceChild(newmess, node.firstChild);
    }


    /* Add caps */
    function Add() {
      try {
        /* Default no message */
        writeMess(nodoMess, "");

        capsule = Number(nodoCapsule.value);
        /* Empty field */
        if (nodoCapsule.value == "" || capsule == 0) {
          writeMess(nodoMess, "Insert number of caps");
          return;
        } else
          /* isNaN */
          if (isNaN(capsule)) {
            writeMess(nodoMess, "Insert valid");
            return;
          }
        else /* Create and update if already exists */
          if (totcaps === "") {
            totcaps = Number(nodoCapsule.value);
            writeMess(nodoMess, "You insert: " + nodoCapsule.value + " caps");
          }
        else {
          totcaps = Number(totcaps) + Number(nodoCapsule.value);
          writeMess(nodoMess, "You insert: " + totcaps + " caps");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        alert("Add " + e);
      }
    }


    /* Globals */
    var nodoAdd;
    var nodoCapsule;
    var totcaps;



    /* Core function */
    function gestoreLoad() {
      try {
        /* Visits */
        nodoAdd = document.getElementById("add");
        nodoCapsule = document.getElementById("caps");
        nodoMess = document.getElementById("messinfoerr");


        /* Events */
        nodoAdd.onclick = Add;

        /* Empty text nodes */
        nodoCapsule.value = "";

        /* Empty message */
        var TextNode = document.createTextNode("");
        nodoMess.appendChild(TextNode);

      } catch (e) {
        alert("gestoreLoad " + e);

      }
    }


    /* Load the code */
    window.onload = gestoreLoad;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Dispenser</h1>
  <p id="messinfoerr"></p>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="caps" />
  <input type="button" id="add" value="Add x caps" />
  <br />

  <br />

</body>

</html>
```

I get "Reference Error: totcaps it's not defined" how to resolve?

Comment: Is totcapsule a misspelling of totcaps?

Comment: sorry...I edited, it doesn't work btw  @SalminSkenderovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would benefit from using `else if` to let your logic become more compact. Your undefined error comes from you using a variable before it is instantiated. I assume you wanted to use `totcaps` there instead. I also simplified some other repetitive things you were doing.

The reason !totcaps does not work as you want (as described in Salmin's answer), is because the `!` mark checks for `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `NaN`. Since you only want to check for `NaN`, do that, but skip the triple `===`, to avoid explicit type check.

```js
/* Globals */
var nodoAdd;
var nodoCapsule;
var totcaps;

/* Mess info/err */
function writeMess(node, mess) {
    newmess = document.createTextNode(mess);
    node.replaceChild(newmess, node.firstChild);
}

/* Add caps */
function Add() {
    try {
        /* Default no message */
        writeMess(nodoMess, "");
        let capsule = Number(nodoCapsule.value);
        let sign = capsule < 0 ? '' : '+';
        
        /* Empty field */
        if (capsule == "" || capsule == 0) {
            writeMess(nodoMess, "Insert number of caps");
        } else if (isNaN(capsule)) {
        /* isNaN */
            writeMess(nodoMess, "Insert valid");
        } else if (totcaps == null) {
        /* Create */
            totcaps = capsule;
            writeMess(nodoMess, "You insert: " + capsule + " caps");
        } else {
        /* Update if already exists */
            totcaps += capsule;
            writeMess(nodoMess, "You insert: " + totcaps + " caps. (" + sign + capsule + ")");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Add " + e);
    }
}

/* Core function */
function gestoreLoad() {
    try {
        /* Visits */
        nodoAdd = document.getElementById("add");
        nodoCapsule = document.getElementById("caps");
        nodoMess = document.getElementById("messinfoerr");


        /* Events */
        nodoAdd.onclick = Add;

        /* Empty text nodes */
        nodoCapsule.value = "";

        /* Empty message */
        var TextNode = document.createTextNode("");
        nodoMess.appendChild(TextNode);

    } catch (e) {
        alert("gestoreLoad " + e);

    }
}


/* Load the code */
window.onload = gestoreLoad;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <h1>Dispenser</h1>
 <p id="messinfoerr"></p>
 <br />
 <input type="text" id="caps" /> 
 <input type="button" id="add" value="Add x caps"/> 
 <br />
 
 <br />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if totcaps is empty like this `if (totcaps === "") {`

What that means is that you are checking if totcaps is an empty string. You can check if the value is falsy like this: `if (!totcaps)` but have in mind that if the value is 0 it will also be considered falsy.

In your code, change the `=== ""` to `=== undefined` and it will work.

https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works! I tried if (totcaps === 'undefined') because I read before on this site, why it didn't work?

Comment: Why it didn't work before was probably because of your spelling error `totcapsule `